# Use mongoose to find a key inside array of object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested, find

I have table of item list (like image). Now I wanna find a object that have `name` contain `searchString`.
I tried query like `db.getCollection('vehicles').find({'result': {'name': 'A-WING FIGHTER'}})` but it look wrong.
How can I get true data in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

by this

```
db.getCollection('vehicles').find({ 'result': { 'name': 'A-WING FIGHTER' } })
```

you are searching for an exact match, so result must be an object with property name only

you should use the dot notation instead

```
db.getCollection('vehicles').find({ 'results.name': 'A-WING FIGHTER' })
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

See if the following command works -

```
db.getCollection('vehicles').find({'results': {'name': 'A-WING FIGHTER'}})
```

You named **result** instead of **results**. Try if it works now...

You can also try using the following code snippet -

```
db.getCollection('vehicles').find({ results.name: 'A-WING FIGHTER' });
```

Comment: Also, `db.getCollection('vehicles').find({'results': 'A-WING FIGHTER'})` should also work as well if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

To search the array of array in MongoDB, you can use $elemMatch operator.

Try this query (This query is according to the image you shared)

```
db.getCollection('items').find({'results': {'$elemMatch: {'$elemMatch: {'name': 'A-WING FIGHTER'}}}})
```

Hope this will be helpfull.